# Taking an absolute maximum of 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

This seems like it would be very obvious to do, but it's alluding me: I want to convert the below code to compute more efficiently over the arrays using `numpy.maximum`:

```
P = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(30,))
for i in range(P.shape[0]): #for element in array
 print max(P[i], np.ones(P.shape[0])[i], key=abs) #take the absolute max
```

More efficient version would be to use:

```
np.maximum(P, np.ones(P.shape[0]))
```

but how can I calculate this as an absolute value, while preserving signs?

Comment: Do you want `-0.5` mapped to `1` or `-1`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I suppose it doesn't matter as I'm keeping the original sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.where`; The absolute values as conditions and original values as the return elements:

```
np.where(np.abs(P) > 1, P, 1)

#array([ 7.91709218, -5.8691354 ,  2.10242613,  3.0050441 ,  1.12334666,
#        3.98891018,  3.60936593, -6.3196432 ,  1.        ,  9.58885417,
#       -2.13595449,  1.49568368, -2.93928838, -7.01366456, -9.1816925 ,
#        4.48940296, -2.3597295 ,  8.66614578, -9.95693121,  8.61132135,
#       -6.24103691,  1.        ,  5.55632026,  4.00445283,  1.        ,
#       -5.17295561,  1.        ,  1.        , -2.94661818,  4.45517007])
```

Comment: Got it, thanks @Psidom. I just stumbled across this solution myself. Not sure it's as efficient as the max, but I guess it will likely be better than element-wise.